# Draw Images on Image/Canvas without showing

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want to create a collage (different images on an image). This works with a canvas which is defined and visible in my XAML. But how can I achieve this without showing the canvas?

```
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new System.Uri(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/" + b.Wert, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup();
double scaleX = (double)w / (double)img.Source.Width;
double scaleY = (double)h / (double)img.Source.Height;
tg.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(scaleX, scaleY));
if (b.Rotation != null)
    tg.Children.Add(new RotateTransform(b.Rotation, w/2, h/2));
tg.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(x, y));
img.RenderTransform = tg;

canvas.Children.Add(img);

double dpi = 96d;
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(collage.Breite, collage.Hoehe, dpi, dpi, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
canvas.UpdateLayout();
rtb.Render(canvas);

// save as png
BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite("test.png"))
{
pngEncoder.Save(fs);
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what "without showing the canvas" actually means. The Image control(s) have to be put into some kind of container. You can't add an Image as child of another Image.

Comment: Can't you just set the Background property of the Canvas to Transparent or some other colour that effectively makes it invisible?

Comment: I set visible before rendering and after save to hidden. This seems to be hacky but it works. It is not rendered to screen.